# What API does Android Studio layout inspector use to access the DOM state of an app?

Tags: android, android-studio

What API does Android Studio layout inspector use to inspect the view tree of a running app?

I have a use case where I need to do something similar.

Comment: Found: https://github.com/Grigory-Rylov/android-layout-inspector which should help identify parts of the Android Studio code base required.

Comment: Thanks, that helped find the answer

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I found that the layout inspector gets its view data here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/layoutinspector/src/com/android/layoutinspector/model/ClientWindow.kt#128

Getting the view data seems to happen from this method:

```
com.android.ddmlib.Client.dumpViewHierarchy
```

Not 100% sure but this also seems to be the same method used underneath by the command

```
adb shell uiautomator dump
```